# Add Placeholder to layer

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow layer with 2 nodes. These are the output nodes of another 2 larger hidden layers. Now I want to add 2 new nodes to this layer, so I end up with 4 nodes in total, and do some last computation. The added nodes are implemented as Placeholders so far, and have a dynamic shape depending on the batch size. Here is a sketch of the net:

[image: Nodes 3 and 4 have to be concatenated to nodes 1 and 2 from the middle layer]

Now I want to concatenate Nodes 3 and 4 to the nodes 1 and 2 of the previously computed layer. I know there is `tf.concat` for this, but I don't understand how to do this correctly.

How do I add Placeholders of the same batchsize as the original net input to a specific layer?

**EDIT:**

When I use `tf.concat` over `axis=1`, I end up with the following problem:

```
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
Weight_matrix = weight_variable([4, 2])
bias = bias_variable([4, 2])
concat = tf.concat((dnn_out, z), 1)
h_fc3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(concat, Weight_matrix) + bias)
```

Adding the bias to the `tf.matmul` result throws an `InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [20,2] vs. [4,2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is batched, probably over the first dimension, you need to concatenate over the second (`axis=1`):

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dnn_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 2)) # replace with your DNN(input) result
additional_nodes = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 2))

concat = tf.concat((dnn_output, additional_nodes), axis=1)
print(concat)
# > Tensor("concat:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32)
dense_output = tf.layers.dense(concat, units=2)
print(dense_output)
# > Tensor("dense/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(dense_output, feed_dict={dnn_output: np.ones((5, 2)),
                                            additional_nodes: np.zeros((5, 2))}))
```

Comment: You are right. But instead of two placeholders, I have only one placeholder for the new values, and the pre-computed values are Tensors

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the comment for `dnn_output`, just replace this placeholder with your actual DNN output tensor. I replaced with a placeholder in my example just to define a variable-size batched tensor.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I edited my question to explain the problem I am facing right now.

Comment: The problem is separate. You are just defining your `bias` with a wrong shape. It should be `(batch_size, 2)` or more simply `(2)` (TF will take care of broadcasting). Note that your whole code could be replaced by `h_fc3 = tf.layers.dense(concat, units=2, activation=tf.nn.relu)`.

Comment: Now that you say it, I finally found my error... Thank you so much!